# CakeEmail Mandril email attachment not getting attached

Tags: php, email, cakephp, attachment, mandrill

I'm aware that there are lot of similar questions on stackoverflow about about this problem and I have tried all of them but none seem to work .

I am trying to send an email with a csv attachment from a cron function. My email is getting sent but there is no attachment . Here is my code

```
$email = new CakeEmail('mandrillSmtp');
$encodedCsv = base64_encode(implode(",",$headers)); 
        //please note that i have debugged encodedCsv. No  errors here

        $email->subject('Report Test');
        $email->from('xxxxx@abc.com');
        $email->to('zzzzz@abc.com');
        $email->emailFormat('html');
        $email->attachments=array(
                array(
                    'content' => $encodedCsv,
                    'type' => "text/csv",
                    'name' => 'report.csv'
                )
            );
        $email->send();
```

Comment: I guess you are missing something in this code. How do the mail know, that you are putting there base64encoded data? You need to specify encoding if I am right.

Comment: I've been through the mandrills docs https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=content I think thats what 'type' => 'text/csv' is for . so thats probably not it

Comment: You may want to have a another, closer look at the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments**, **http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-CakeEmail.html#_attachments**

Comment: @ndm The 'traditional' cakeemail is sligthly different from the mandrill way it seems. in cakeemail attachments is a function whereas with mandrill api it is a property . anyway i have taken a look at the link you've posted and tried the following: $email->attachments($uri). where uri is the uri from a csv file handle . but i keep getting a : 'File not found " " ' while trying to attach the csv . I have created my file using fopen('php://temp//fname.csv',''rw') . I understand that this is a completely different issue from my original problem but i havent found a solution yet :(

Comment: Mandrill is an E-Mail infrastructure with SMTP integration, REST APIs, and API clients for various programming languages. None of this will have any influence on how the CakePHP core code works! There is no `CakeEmail::$attachments` property, not even the Mandrill PHP API client has such a property anywhere, and no matter what SMTP server your are using with `CakeEmail`, it will not cause such a property to magically appear, that's not how any of this works. The Mandrill REST API supports an `attachments` parameter for `/messages/send.json` requests, but you're not using the REST API.

Comment: Regarding your other problem, a "_URI from a file handle_"? So you're basically passing `php://temp//fname.csv`? Please update your question with the appropiate code, the _exact_ error message and the corresponding stacktrace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for all the help . I finally got my code working . thanks @ndm for your reminder that the mandrill api is completely different from CakeEmail(brief moment of dumbness for me). 
I solved my issue of not being able to attach a file written to the php://temp output stream too by using tmpfile() instead of fopen('php://temp') . for some reason i cant access files written to the temp stream even if i have their uri's 
Anyway heres my code. hope that it helps someone

```
$email = new CakeEmail('mandrillSmtp');
if($handle =tmpfile()){
                    fputcsv($handle, $headers); 
                    fputcsv($data)    ;

                }


        $fileMeta = stream_get_meta_data($handle);
        $uri = $fileMeta['uri'];


        $email->subject('Report Test');
        $email->from('xxx@abc.com');
        $email->to('zzz@abc.com');
        $email->emailFormat('html');
        $email->attachments(array('test.csv'=>array('mimetype'=>'text/csv','file' => $uri)));

        $email->send();

        fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to attach the CSV file, then you need the path to the CSV file and I suggest you make the attachment array as follows:

```
 $email->attachments = array(
array('file' => 'pathToCSVFIle/myCSvFile.csv')
        );
```